# Delphi: function Result not emptied during for loop

Tags: delphi, function, stack

is this normal?

```
for a := 1 to 10 do
    x.test;

   x.test;
   x.test;
   x.test;

function test: string;
begin
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}  DebugMessage('result check = '+Result,3); {$ENDIF}
   result := result + 'a';
end;

10:39:59: result check = 
10:39:59: result check = a
10:39:59: result check = aa
10:39:59: result check = aaa
10:39:59: result check = aaaa
10:39:59: result check = aaaaa
10:39:59: result check = aaaaaa
10:39:59: result check = aaaaaaa
10:39:59: result check = aaaaaaaa
10:39:59: result check = aaaaaaaaa

10:39:59: result check = 
10:39:59: result check = 
10:39:59: result check =
```

function result stack is not freed during a for loop? :O

Comment: This has been treated before at SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Result` is treated as an implicit `var` parameter to your function.

Imagine if you wrote it out explicitly this way:

```
procedure test(var result: string);
begin
  result := result + 'a';
end;

for i := 1 to 10 do
  test(s);
```

Then you would expect it to append to `s`.

The fact that you are throwing away `Result` each time you call it is why the compiler sometimes decides to finalise it.  As @gabr points out, it elects not to finalize this implicit variable when inside a loop as an optimisation.

If you were to assign the result of `test` to a string every time you called `test` then you'd see the string get longer each time, it would never be re-initialized.

This is why you should always initialize your result variable. It looks like a local variable, but it is best thought of as a `var` parameter.

Comment: +1 for the example, but please include the comment you made to my now deleted answer into your answer (`if you assign the result to something outside of the function, then the initialization will happen once and once only`)

Comment: @Cosmin That was already there but I've made it stand out now as a new paragraph (the penultimate one)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, great answer!  Today I had similar problem with dynamic arrays, it was easy to fix, but this helped me truly understand.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you should always initialize function result. Don't assume it will be set to proper value just because it is of a dynamic (in this case string) type.

Comment: Then the the compiler should emit a "Not initialized" warning just as with non-lifetime-managed types.