# Left over string in function result

Tags: delphi, function, concatenation

I have a function inside an object that concatenates JSON text. The function result is a String - the resulting JSON text. The function simply appends text to the end of the result...

```
function TDestination.GetAsJSON: String;
  procedure A(const Text: String);
  begin
    Result:= Result + Text + sLineBreak;
  end;
begin
  A('        {');
  A('            "name":"'+EncodeStr(FName)+'",');
  A('            "directory":"'+EncodeStr(FDirectory)+'",');
  A('            "description":"'+EncodeStr(FDescription)+'"');
  A('        }');
end;
```

This function is called repeatedly in a loop from within another parent object...

```
function TDestinations.GetAsJSON: String;
  procedure A(const Text: String);
  begin
    Result:= Result + Text + sLineBreak;
  end;
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  A('    [');
  for X := 0 to Count - 1 do begin
    if X > 0 then A('        ,');
    Result:= Result + Items[X].AsJSON;
  end;
  A('    ]');
end;
```

In the second function, `Items[X].AsJSON` is calling the first function.

The problem is that the second (and all further) calls to `TDestination.GetAsJSON` still have the string sitting in the function result from the last time it was called.

The solution is to simply initialize the result with `Result:= '';` at the beginning of the function. But the question is why should I have to? Why does this string get left behind?

What makes it puzzling is that each different call to this function is from within a completely separate instance of that object. I would understand if it was the exact same object instance, but it's not.

Comment: You must handle Result as a local variable

Comment: Treating it that way is what leads to the problem in this question, @Sir. `Result` is nominally a local variable, but it doesn't act like other local string variables. Other string variables are always initialized to empty, but `Result` is not.

Comment: Result isn't a local variable. It's a var parameter. One of the worst decisions ever made in the design of Delphi. You are at the mercy of the caller. And there's an optimisation for loops that burns you. This is a dupe though. I will look it up tomorrow. There's some good stuff at the other Q IIRC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi: function Result not emptied during for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102843/delphi-function-result-not-emptied-during-for-loop)  But there should be a better explanation at the accepted answer there. I'll try to polish it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guido Gybels in his article "[Using Assembler in Delphi](http://www.guidogybels.eu/docs/Using%20Assembler%20in%20Delphi.pdf)" denotes that functions with long string type result return it as implicit var-parameter. So compiler treats your function as:

```
(hidden)var 
          temp_s: String;
procedure GetAsJSON(var temps: String);
...
GetAsJSON(temp_s);
UsedResult1 := temp_s;
...
GetAsJSON(temp_s);
UsedResult2 := temp_s;
```

So hidden string can retain its value under certain conditions.

Anyway, you're not relying on the initialization of integer result by 0, right?

Edit: This behavior is documented: [Delphi help link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Program_Control) (section Handling Function Results)

Comment: +1 for the official documentation quoting the Delphi link. Note that under x64, this is not the case: the `string` result is passed as 2nd parameter, not as a last one. But for the question, it is the same as in x86: the result is *never* set to `''` at the beginning of the `function`. It will be `''` only if the destination variable is already `''`, which won't be the case within a loop.